# Exp:resso Store - Customise Admin Order Print View

Tags: expresso-store, templates, orders

[image: Print Button]

I'm trying to work out what the best way to edit the layout of the Order Print View is so that it can fit with my clients Packing Slip Paper (it has special sticker areas for the shipping address etc).

In earlier versions of Store there was a PDF view that I have been able to edit, but since 2.4.0 this has been replaced with an HTML print view. This HTML view seems to be the main display template with print CSS applied. I'm always lothe to start editing core files, so any pointers much appreciated.

Any pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it without editing Store source files is to write some javascript and/or css that manipulates the layout and then inject that into the order detail view with an add-on like [CP CSS & JS](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) or [hijack](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/hijack).